# Trouble with Soundcloud Tracks

Tags: soundcloud

I uploaded a sound to soundcloud, and due to image errors, the media will not play. I've deleted the file multiple times, but it keeps re-appearing without and with the image. However, in both cases, it claims the sound is not streamable. Someone please help me delete this sound and upload it properly.

Comment: You may want to contact Soundcloud support for this.

Comment: What TheDude said, http://help.soundcloud.com/